# Flutter Textfield size is too small while typing in small screens like watch displays

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

The size of the display area is too small compared to the free spaces around it. This happens in small screens displays like watches. How to increase the visibility of the sentence while typing?

Code sample

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              filled: true,
            ),
            style: FontSizeModifier.body(context),
            controller: textConroller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
            maxLines: null,
            minLines: null,
            expands: true,
            autofocus: true,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
            enableSuggestions: true,
          )
```

Comment: contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8) is hard coded and in small screens is gonna cause that, you could use layout builder in order to create a responsive layout. You can watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EH92XnCU1Cc.
Or
You can easily remove that padding or parent elementes that have padding around your text field, but in bigger screens it might not look good.

Comment: I will test your suggestions and update you here. Thanks. @JuanCarlosRamónCondezo